# Why redis instance is dropping keys

Tags: redis

Here is my Redis graph from graphite for the past 72 hours displaying current_keys.

[image]

as you may notice one instance ( green ) is dropping keys regularly, while other one is ok.. Both of them were configured with Chef and running same Redis version ( redis_version:2.6.5 ) and same config.

Any ideas what could cause keys to drop? Both instances are behind nutcracker/twemproxy ( redis proxy from Twitter https://github.com/twitter/twemproxy ) so should get equal amount of keys..

Answer (score 1):

I’d start with checking for what happens around 1 am, each day; possible causes…

- Chef-client is running with an `--interval` and causes a reset (check `/var/log/chef/*`)
- Bad permissions on the `jetpack` host and `logrotate` (or other automated tasks) fail (check `/var/log/syslog`)
- Leftover crontabs on host `jetpack` (because Chef is not transactional and does not delete artifacts of removed provider calls; check `/etc/cron.d/`)

The only way I’ve been able to fix the `--interval` behavior of chef-client is to restart a host. I’ve then changed all chef commands to include the `--once` argument.